# No RDL Report option in Add New Item of ASP.net web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013

Hello I am trying to create a website in VS 2013 and trying to add a report (.RDL) in the project. But when I do Add New Item, I am not able to see any report or report wizard in the dialog.

I did installed SSDT Tools for SSRS as well but still I didn't got any report template/editor in the visual studio 2013. Previously I was using vs 2012 and later when I installed vs 2013 I was able to get the report template in the VS 2013 but when I formatted my PC, I just installed 2013 but no option for reports or report viewer in the tool box.

[image]

Can anyone please guide me to get the template back ?

Comment: Those templates are part of SSDT 2013. Are you sure you re-downloaded SSDT 2013 after formatting?

Comment: Yes I did installed SSDT but still I am not getting the option. Is there anything else I have to install ?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your list of installed templates, I think you got the wrong version of SSDT, since you have options for SQL Server templates, but not Business Intelligence. There are two very distinct versions of SSDT: SSDT for regular database tooling, and SSDT-BI (contains templates for SSAS, SSRS, SSIS projects).

Please follow this link and download SSDT-BI for 2013:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313

This should install the desired templates.